# Need help migrating apache directives to nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, configuration

To keep it simple, I'm trying to find the nginx alternative to the following apache htaccess directives:

```
<Files track>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<Files ttrack>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<Files qtrack>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

I have several of these directives, and it is not possible to rename the files with a php extension so that's out of the question. I just need to know how I can get these extensionless files to be run as php scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong (it's several years I don't use Apache), you can try:

```
location /(track|ttrack|qtrack) {
  // the stuff to use php-cgi like:
  fastcgi_pass  upstreamServerPool;
  // ...
}
```

This will match all requests for url like /track or /ttrack or /qtrack.